# Parsing of anonymous function evaluation in R

Tags: r

This may be related to lazy evaluation, but it was definitely not what I was expecting.  It may also be related to the behavior that makes an implicit semi-colon, where possible, at the end of each input line.

```
> (function(x) x * 10)(10)
[1] 100
```

expected.

```
> function(x) x * 10
function(x) x * 10
```

expected.

```
> (function(x) x * 10)
function(x) x * 10
```

here he strips off the () and evaluates, assuming that there is no actuals to follow

```
> (function(x) x * 10
+ )(10)
[1] 100
```

omit the closing ) and he waits for it and the actuals.

```
> (function(x) x * 10)
function(x) x * 10
> (10)
[1] 10
```

but not if the ) is on the same line.

```
> (function(x) x * 10)(
+ 10)
[1] 100
```

but the ( for the actuals can go on the first line and the behavior is as expected.

I would have expected the parser to recognize an anonymous function call (f(x)) in progress and hold off evaluation until the arguments have been specified.  It will do this if the last thing on the line is an (, but not if the ( is the first thing in the following line.

So basically these )( have to be together on the first line or the second line in order for it to recognize an anonymous call in progress.  Sort of argues for explicit ; termination ala perl, etc.

This example is somewhat trivial for exposition.  One could put it all on one line and have done with it.  The problem is not as trivial when trying to maintain a functional programming style where the argument is not 10 but the output of another anonymous function (or several).

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with lazy evaluation. That's just how the interactive read process is set up. It waits, not until functions have their arguments specified, but rather until there is a complete expression that will return a value. Since a function is a legitimate value, it returns that. The action is different when `source`-ing from afile. That action has no read-eval-print. It's more a parse-eval-act loop. (I thought this was in the R-FAQ, but I've failed to find it so far. Until I can find a better reference, I'd refer you to `?source`, where the differences between file handling and command line handling is discussed.) If you want to establish a style that avoids this ambiguity, then use `"{"` right after the argument list specification.( I think it gives you more informative error messages when you screw up.)

Comment: Thanks.  I looked at that, and learned something.  In actual practice I'm using Rscript in a #! file under unix.  The behavior is subtly different there as well.  The evaluation is correct but the command echo is different depending on where the ) and ( go.